# При получении ID последней дабаленой записи в БД через PDO всегда возвращается 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

мое соединение с PDO

```
class Db {
  private $host = "localhost";
  private $user = "root";
  private $pwd = "root";
  private $dbName = "test";

  public function connect() {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName;
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pwd);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
  }
```

Я наследуюсь от него в классе People

```
class People extends Db {
    private $id;
    private $first_name;
    private $last_name;
    private $date_of_birth;
    private $sex;
    private $city_of_birth;

    public function addPeople($first_name, $last_name, $date_of_birth, $sex, $city_of_birth) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO people(first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, sex, city_of_birth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$first_name, $last_name, $date_of_birth, $sex, $city_of_birth]);
        var_dump($this->connect()->lastInsertId());
      }
```

Но после операции Insert новые записи добавляются, но id последней всталенной записи всегда равно 0.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что каждый вызов вашего метода `connect()` открывает новое соединение с базой данных. В котором, соответственно, ещё не было никаких `insert` и возвращать нечего. Откройте соединение с базой, сохраните его, и используйте одно в скрипте. Открывать новое соединение на каждый запрос не только бесполезно, но и исключительно вредно.

PS: People вообще не должен наследовать Db.